# Formatting Java Instant to "YYYYMMdd" adds an extra year?

Tags: java, datetime, dateformatter

It's been a long day and my brain is tired so maybe I'm completely missing something, but how come when I run this line,

```
System.out.println(
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd")
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
    .format(Instant.parse("2020-12-31T08:00:00Z"))
  )
)
```

I get `20211231` instead of `20201231`? Where does the extra year come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want lowercase y -

```
        System.out.println(
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
                    .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                    .format(Instant.parse("2020-12-31T08:00:00Z"))
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

The capital `Y` represents Week based year as per official documentation of [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). More about how it calculates over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year).

This works fine if you use date formatter with smallcase `y` as `yyyyMMdd`.

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
            .format(Instant.parse("2020-12-31T08:00:00Z")));
```

Output:

```
20201231
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [the docs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), `Y` is the *week-based* year. That means that the year number of the week in which the date falls, is returned.

The fact is that 31st of December, 2020, is actually week 1 of 2021, hence 2021 is returned instead of 2020.

You probably want to use `yyyy` instead.